# How to display only extracted files with tar, not the ones which are not extracted /not overwritten?

Tags: linux, tar, raspbian, console, output

I'm extracting a tar archive with `tar -xf /tmp/update.tar -C / -v --keep-newer-files`.
The `-v` Option is to display all files processed, the `--keep-newer-files` Option is self explaining.

Due to all files already exist I get the following output:

```
usr/local/bin/execstate.log
tar: Current ‘usr/local/bin/execstate.log’ is newer or same age
usr/local/bin/dblist.sh
tar: Current ‘usr/local/bin/dblist.sh’ is newer or same age
usr/local/bin/dbblacklist.sh
tar: Current ‘usr/local/bin/dbblacklist.sh’ is newer or same age
```

I know, that the `--warning-no-ignore-newer` Option switches the warning of, but then the output is:

```
usr/local/bin/execstate.log
usr/local/bin/dblist.sh
usr/local/bin/dbblacklist.sh
```

But none of these files will be extracted!

I just want to display the files which are extracted (if they do not already exist)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `star`:

```
star -C / -xv -nowarn < /tmp/update.tar
```

It seems that `gtar` did not fully copy the features from `star` ;-)

OSS friendly Linux distros have `star` binary packages, for other distros, compile it after fetching a recent `schilytools` source archive from http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

The current star release is 1.6.1. Note that the option `-nowarn` and the default to only extract files that are newer in the archive is from 1985, which is long before `gtar` started.

Note that since Linux implements slow filesystems, it is recommended to check the `star` man page for the option `-no-fsync`. This allows you to switch `star` into a mode that is as insecure as you are used with `gtar`.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no ```star``` or ```gtar ``` package for Raspbian Buster, at least i did not find it...

Comment: Linux usually does not come with a real `tar` program but rather with `gtar` installed as `tar`. If you have a OSS friendly Linux distro, you of course get a `star` binary package. On other platforms, you may need to compile it yourself. See edited answer. On a RASPI, the compilation of the schilytools sources takes one hour.

Comment: @WBK have you been successfull?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but the effort of compiling is too high for me. After all, it is just an output on the screen...

Comment: @WBK `schilytools` is not as hard to compile as other software, since there is a modern build system in use. You just unpack the archive and call `make` at top directory level inside the unpacked tree. Call `make .help` for more targets. Since I do not trust `gtar` compiling and installing `star` is the first thing, I do on a new machine.

Comment: Thank you, it works!!!